# SiteEdit never stops loading the components and schemas

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, dd4t, siteedit

We have implemented SiteEdit with DD4T using SitEdit 2009 SP1 for Tridion 2011 SP1 for the first time and we are getting a message from SiteEdit that "Loading components and Schemas" and it is giving this message constantly and we are unable to edit the content as it is still loading. Can anybody let me know the issue?

The page source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>News</title>
    <link href="/FirstDD4TMVCApplicationsiteedit/Content/Site.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/FirstDD4TMVCApplicationsiteedit/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/SiteEdit/App_Themes/SiteEdit/Calendar.css" type="text/css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/SiteEdit/App_Themes/SiteEdit/SiteEditBorders.css" 
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span>
    <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Presentation: {"ID" : "cp_1", "ComponentID" : "tcm:8-31855", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:8-31851-32", "ComponentVersion" : 1, "IsQueryBased" : false  } -->

    <div>
      <span>
        <!-- Start SiteEdit Component Field: {"ID" : "ContentHeading1", "XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:Heading[1]", "IsMultiValued" : false} -->
        Hello this is test
        <h3>TestNews</h3>
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <!-- SiteEdit Settings: { "PageID" : "tcm:8-31856-64", "PageVersion" : 2, "TargetTypeID" : "", "ComponentPresentationLocation" : 1}  -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

One more question: what is the significance of the following tag and its attributes in SiteEdit page tag which is being automatically generated by SiteEdit while using with DD4T?

```
"BluePrinting" : {"PageContext" : "tcm:0-0-1", "ComponentContext" : "tcm:0-8-1", "PublishContext" : "tcm:0-8-1" }
```

Comment: Hi LK, Thanks for posting your SDL Tridion questions here on SO - You might consider committing to the Stack Exchange proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 to help us getting a dedicated Q&A area. Hope to see you there.

Answer (score 4):

Issue got ressolved :)
We just need to surround or add span tags to SiteEdit tags.

For example

```
<span>
@Html.SiteEditPage(Model)
</span>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Compare in IIS Manager the following virtual directories under

```
[CME Website]/WebUI/Editors

[CME Website]/WebUI/Models
```

With

```
[SiteEdit Website]/WebUI/Editors

[SiteEdit Website]/WebUI/Models
```

Those directories should contain the same items/structure. If not, I have seen that error happening.

The forever "Loading components and Schemas" also can happen if popup window that SiteEdit pops during login is blocked by a popup blocker.